# MySQL json_arrayagg with left join without results

Tags: mysql

With MySQL 8.0 the [json_arrayagg](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg) was introduced, this made it possible to aggregate json results.

Now I want to use it to show the tags attached to a message.

Currently there are three tables for this (simplefied)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS feed_message (
  id CHAR(36) PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS feed_tag (
  id CHAR(36) PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS feed_message_tag (
  message CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
  tag CHAR(36) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (message, tag)
);
```

So there is one table contain the message, one that holds all the tags and a table that hold the connections between tags and messages (feed_message_tag).

The response I am seeking is a list of messages with a column of tags which is an array of objects with there id + name. So something as followed

```
[{"id": 1, "name": "Foo"}]
```

Now the examples I find use (inner) joins which means a message must have a tag, but that is not always the case so left join is used. Which brings me to the following query I use

```
SELECT
  json_arrayagg(
      json_object(
          'id',
          ft.id,
          'name',
          ft.name
      )
  ) as 'tags'
FROM feed_message fm
LEFT JOIN feed_message_tag fmt ON fmt.message = fm.id
LEFT JOIN feed_tag ft ON fmt.tag = ft.id
GROUP BY fm.id
```

The problem now is that if one message has no tags I get the following output as `tags`.

```
[{"id": null, "name": null}]
```

After some searching and tweaking I came to the following change for the `tags` column

```
IF(
    fmt.message IS NULL,
    json_array(),
    json_arrayagg(
      json_object(
        'id',
        ft.id,
        'name',
        ft.name
      )
    )
  ) as 'tags'
```

Is this the intended behaviour or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You could use a correlated subquery in the select clause. But then you would get `NULL` instead of an empty array.

Comment: Saved my life with an `if` after my hours of digging. I tried to do a subquery to first select those item, and embed those inside the array with an outter select, but no luck. Yours is just clean and easy.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your method may be the only way to do this.

The reason is that `NULL` is a valid value to include in JSON objects. While most aggregation functions ignore nulls, so they properly ignore non-matching rows that come from `LEFT JOIN`, it would be a problem for `JSON_ARRAYAGG()`. It would prevent you from including null values in other situations. There's no way to distinguish explicit nulls from `LEFT JOIN` nulls.

Comment: Unfortunately that returns `[null]`

Comment: Hmm, I guess that makes sense for the reason in my last paragraph. So your way looks like the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use Having and check count of your record with JSON_ARRAYAGG() function in your query HAVING  count(0) > 0