# add condition to mysql json_arrayagg function

Tags: mysql

I have a json query that gives me json of a joined table of person and pets:

```
SELECT json_object(
  'personId', p.id,
  'pets', json_arrayagg(json_object(
    'petId', pt.id,
    'petName', pt.name
  ))
  )
FROM person p LEFT JOIN pets pt
ON p.id = pt.person_id
GROUP BY p.id;
```

my issue is that person can have 0 or more pets, and when a person have 0 pets I get list with 1 empty pet, and what I would like to get in that case is empty list.

this is what I get:

```
{
  "personId": 1,
  "pets": [
    {
      "petId": null,
      "petName": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

and I need:

```
{
  "personId": 1,
  "pets": []
}
```

is that possible?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49960156/mysql-json-arrayagg-with-left-join-without-results

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The problem is that `LEFT JOIN` still returns columns from the table you're joining with, it just sets their values to `NULL`.

You can use `IF` to test `COUNT(pt.id)`, as this won't count null values.

```
SELECT json_object(
  'personId', p.id,
  'pets', IF(COUNT(pt.id) = 0, JSON_ARRAY(),
             json_arrayagg(json_object(
                'petId', pt.id,
                'petName', pt.name
                )
            ))
  )
FROM person p LEFT JOIN pets pt
ON p.id = pt.person_id
GROUP BY p.id;
```

Comment: Working Perfect.. THanks

Comment: Thank you so much, **IF( COUNT(...), ... , ... )** is a really nice trick, it had to be an aggregated function but I couldn't figure out which and how to use! )

Answer (score 7):

Another possibility is to put the aggregation in a correlated subquery and use `coalesce()` to replace it with an empty array if no rows exist.

```
SELECT json_object('personID', p.id,
                   'pets', coalesce((SELECT json_arrayagg(json_object('petId', t.id,
                                                                      'petName', t.name))
                                            FROM pets t
                                            WHERE t.person_id = p.id),
                                    json_array()))
       FROM person p;
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding another option:

```
select IFNULL( /*expression of select ...JSON_ARRAYAGG(
                                    JSON_OBJECT(....*/,JSON_ARRAY()) jarrayaggAlias
```

Cleaner below:

```
IFNULL( expression, ,JSON_ARRAY()) jarrayaggAlias
```

Result:

```
/* { jarrayaggAlias: []  }*/
```

If you swap *alt_value* for *IFNULL* to select `[]`, then all your results will be stringyfied.