# get related row data as an object in each row

Tags: mysql, json

I have a `users` table and a `usersPermissions` table and I want to get a list of all the users and insert a column in each user's row called `permissions` which would be an object of all of the user's permissions from the `userPermisssions` table.

Here is pseudo-code:

```
SELECT
  u.*,
  u.id as user,
  (SELECT p.* from userPermissions p where p.userId = user) as permissions
FROM
  users u
```

I want the permissions column to be a json object of all of the matching rows from userPermissions.

Ive spent a couple hours with chatgpt getting things like this that never work:

```
SELECT u.*, 
    (SELECT JSON_OBJECTAGG(p.permissionId, p.userId, p.id) 
     FROM userpermissions p 
     WHERE p.userId = u.id) as permissions
FROM users u
```

Thanks for any help you can give me!!

`users`:
id,
firstName,
lastName,
email,
phone,
etc...

`usersPermission`:
id,
userId (userId = users.id),
permissionId,

Result I would like:

```
[
        {
            id: 1,
            firstName: 'Joe',
            lastName: 'Blo',
            email: 'em@em.com',
            phone: '7025556666',
            permissions: [
                {
                    id: 55,
                    userId: 1,
                    permissionId: 15
                },
                {
                    id: 58,
                    userId: 1,
                    permissionId: 17
                },
                {
                    id: 59,
                    userId: 1,
                    permissionId: 19
                }
            ]
        }, 
        ...
    ]
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide some sample data and expected result. What sort of relationship exists between `users` and `usersPermissions`? To me it looks like _one-to-many_ so it's unclear what the result should look like

Comment: @Phil I tried adding more relevant info...

Comment: Right, so you want an array, not an object. Looks like you'd need a combination of `JSON_ARRAYAGG()` and `JSON_OBJECT()`

Comment: yes an array of objects

Comment: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want a combination of `JSON_ARRAYAGG()` to aggregate the permissions grouped by *user* and `JSON_OBJECT()` to construct the objects in the array.

For example

```sql
SELECT
  u.id,
  u.firstName,
  u.lastName,
  u.email,
  u.phone,
  JSON_ARRAYAGG(
    JSON_OBJECT(
      'id', up.id,
      'userId', up.userId,
      'permissionId', up.permissionId
    )
  ) as permissions
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN userPermissions up ON u.id = up.userId
GROUP BY u.id, u.firstName, u.lastName, u.email, u.phone;
```

Note that for any user with no corresponding permissions, you'll get a singleton array with

```json
[ { "id": null, "userId": null, "permissionId": null } ]
```

I couldn't think of a neat way to make it an empty array due to the object structure you want.

---

Actually, there is an answer to that last part here - [add condition to mysql json_arrayagg function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53952498/283366)

Comment: Yes, create JSON data after an outer join so individual attribute and their null value can be displayed. But I was wondering if it's necessary to do so. After the OP adds the permissions column for table `users`, the default value is null. So it might be better to leave it be as a reminder of no update using table `usersPermission` ,which is more distinguishable than JSON format.

Comment: @blabla_bingo sorry, I don't really understand your comment. OP isn't adding any columns

Comment: My apologies. I thought the OP was going to add a new column to table `users` as OP said `I want to get a list of all the users and insert a column in each user's row called permissions` But if the `permissions` column already exists in the table, the default value is more likely to be null at the moment. That's why I thought it might be better to just leave it be if an update statement using inner join with table `usersPersmission` does not match the join condition.